# Print numbers in columns c++

Tags: c++, string, loops, formatting

I want to print a string array containing numbers organized in columns.

The array contains {`"2","1","3","16","8","3","4","1","2"`}

I want to print them in this form

> ```
> 2       16        4
> 1       8         1
> 3       3         2
> ```

I tried to do it but it print out like this

```
 2      
 1
 3
        16
        8
        3
                  4
                  1
                  2
```

Any help ?

My code :

```
std::string arr[] = {"2","1","3","16","8","3","4","1","2"};
std::string s="";
int count=0;

for (int i = 0; i <3 ; ++i) 
{
    for (count; count <(i+1)*3 ; ++count) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <i ; ++j) 
        {
            std::cout<<"\t";
        }
            std::cout<<arr[count]<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

**The main problem in my code that the next column always start in a new line after the previous column ends .**

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you posted the code that prints the numbers.

Comment: Please include the code that you have tried

Comment: Transpose your matrix ?

Comment: *The array contains [2-1-3-16-8-3-4-1-2]* -- This is not C++.  That could mean anything.  Please post actual code, not descriptions of some abstract list of numbers.

Comment: Print every third number, then every third number starting from the second number, then every third number starting from the third number. Use [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) to make the numbers align. If it's in a 2D array, just iterate through it with the loop for the second dimension on the outside.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to post my code , i posted it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to print a string array containing numbers organized in
>   columns. The array contains `{"2","1","3","16","8","3","4","1","2"}`
>
> I want to print them in this form
>
> ```
> 2       16        4
> 1       8         1
> 3       3         2
> ```

For the the given code of yours, you can do following changes to achieve the result.

- Find the array length using `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);`.
- Make a loop according to the size of your matrix. This is to iterate through the rows.
- Using a second loop, until it gets to the maximum array length, print each array elements. The index increments according to the matrix size.
- Make a line break after each time inner-loop has done printing.

**PS**: Using `std::string` array is a bad idea. You can use instead of that, simple arrays, `std::array` or `std::vector`, as it look like you want an integer array/ matrix.

See output **[HERE](https://www.ideone.com/mA8rlH)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::string arr[]={"2","1","3","16","8","3","4","1","2"};
   const int arrlength = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
   const int matrixSize = 3;

   for(int row = 0; row < matrixSize; ++row)
   {
      for (int index = row; index < arrlength ; index += matrixSize)
         std::cout << arr[index] << std::setw(5);
      std::cout << "\n";
   }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2   16    4    
1    8    1    
3    3    2
```